# Flutter Dynamic Dropdown Menu with Additional Option (adding value or typing in as text field)

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, textfield

I would like to ask about the Flutter Dynamic Dropdown Menu. So, currently my option is only displaying the value that stored in the Firestore, if let said I would like to provide the user additional option to add new value into the list by clicking "Add new value" option and navigate to the adding page or how to let them type in the value in TextField instead of they only can select the options? I need help, anyone can state how to implement it by modifying the code. Appreciate those help, thank you.

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});
  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Center(
          child: Text('Dropdown Button'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('options')
                .orderBy("option")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                    child: Text("Some error occured ${snapshot.error}"));
              }
              List<DropdownMenuItem> optionItems = [];
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                final selectOption = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed.toList();
                if (selectOption != null) {
                  for (var option in selectOption) {
                    optionItems.add(
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: option.id,
                        child: Text(
                          option['option'],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButton(
                        underline: const SizedBox(),
                        isExpanded: true,
                        hint: const Text(
                          "Select the options",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        value: selectedValue,
                        items: optionItems,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedValue = value;
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Current Options Displaying]

Answer (score 0):

try updating your _HomePageState:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
String? selectedValue;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: const Center(
      child: Text('Dropdown Button'),
    ),
  ),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children:[
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('options')
            .orderBy("option")
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
                child: Text("Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}"));
          }
          List<DropdownMenuItem> optionItems = [];
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            final selectOption = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed.toList();
            if (selectOption != null) {
              for (var option in selectOption) {
                optionItems.add(
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: option.id,
                    child: Text(
                      option['option'],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
            optionItems.add(
              DropdownMenuItem(
                value: 'new',
                child: Text('Add new value'),
              ),
            );

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: DropdownButton(
                  underline: const SizedBox(),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: const Text(
                    "Select the options",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  value: selectedValue,
                  items: optionItems,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    if (value == 'new') {
                      // Navigate to the page where the user can add a new value
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AddNewValuePage(),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedValue = value;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      )
    ]),
  ),
 );
}
```

}

Create the AddNewValuePage class:

```
class AddNewValuePage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Add New Value'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // Your text fields for adding a new value
          // ...

          // Save button
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Save the new value to Firestore
              // ...

              // Pop the current route from the navigation stack
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
```

}

Make sure to replace the comment placeholders with the actual code

Comment: I still encounter one problem, because I need to save the value into another firebase collection but why the selected value that saved is the document id so how can I get the text value of Option #1 instead of the document id?

Comment: its a question related to firebase collection. Im not that familiar with firebase. 
is flutter part helping ? because its the theme of the main question :)